# Angular 7 Bootstrap directives don't load

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I have this code:

Component html:

```
<td>
  <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
    <a ngbDropdownToggle>
      <fa-icon [icon]="faEllipsis"></fa-icon>
    </a>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
      <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
      <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
      <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Component ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Group } from "../../../common/models/Group";
import { faEllipsisV } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';


@Component({
  selector: '[study-groups-row]',
  templateUrl: './study-groups-row.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./study-groups-row.component.css']
})
export class StudyGroupsRowComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() group: Group;
  faEllipsis = faEllipsisV;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

and this in my module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StudyComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    CreateNewStudyComponent,
    LoadingBackgroundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StudyModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    library.add(faSpinner, faSave, faAngleDown);
  }
}
```

I have this in my package.json:

```
 "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
 "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
 "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.1",
```

It compiles without error and there are not errors in console but dropdown don't work? There are no bootstrap classes added? Should they be added dynamically by directives?

I've added breakpoint in vendor.js in line:

```
var NgbDropdownMenu = /** @class */ (function () {
    function NgbDropdownMenu(dropdown, _elementRef, _renderer) {
```

but it don't paused when I've refreshed the page. My angular.json have boostrap css and it's loaded.

What I've missed? [Docs say that you only need add import into ngModule](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started).

**EDIT**: docs say that it support Angular 7.0.0 I was using 7.2. I've downgraded to 7.0 but it still don't work. I've tried to add first component from docs (Accordion) and got this error now (dropdown give no visible indication that it's running):

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbAccordion" ("<ngb-accordion [ERROR ->]#acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0">
  <ngb-panel title="Simple">
    <ng-template ngbPanelCo"): ng:///StudyModule/StudyGroupsComponent.html@0:15
'ngb-panel' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngb-panel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-panel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0">
  [ERROR ->]<ngb-panel title="Simple">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit"): ng:///StudyModule/StudyGroupsComponent.html@1:2
'ngb-panel' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngb-panel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-panel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
  [ERROR ->]<ngb-panel>
    <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
      <span>&#9733; <b>Fancy</b> title &#9733;</span>
"): ng:///StudyModule/StudyGroupsComponent.html@11:2
'ngb-accordion' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngb-accordion' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-accordion' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0">
  <ngb-panel title="Simple">
    <ng-temp"): ng:///StudyModule/StudyGroupsComponent.html@0:0
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2547)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:19495)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25041)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25028)
    at compiler.js:24971
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:24971)
    at compiler.js:24881
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2538)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:24880)
```

Vendor.js have this code:

```
        NgbAccordion.decorators = [{
            type: _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["Component"],
            args: [{
                selector: 'ngb-accordion',
                exportAs: 'ngbAccordion',
                host: {
                    'class': 'accordion',
                    'role': 'tablist',
                    '[attr.aria-multiselectable]': '!closeOtherPanels'
                },
                template: "\n    <ng-template ngFor let-panel [ngForOf]=\"panels\">\n      <div class=\"card\">\n        <div role=\"tab\" id=\"{{panel.id}}-header\" [class]=\"'card-header ' + (panel.type ? 'bg-'+panel.type: type ? 'bg-'+type : '')\">\n          <h5 class=\"mb-0\">\n            <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-link\"\n              (click)=\"toggle(panel.id)\" [disabled]=\"panel.disabled\" [class.collapsed]=\"!panel.isOpen\"\n              [attr.aria-expanded]=\"panel.isOpen\" [attr.aria-controls]=\"panel.id\">\n              {{panel.title}}<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]=\"panel.titleTpl?.templateRef\"></ng-template>\n            </button>\n          </h5>\n        </div>\n        <div id=\"{{panel.id}}\" role=\"tabpanel\" [attr.aria-labelledby]=\"panel.id + '-header'\"\n             class=\"collapse\" [class.show]=\"panel.isOpen\" *ngIf=\"!destroyOnHide || panel.isOpen\">\n          <div class=\"card-body\">\n               <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]=\"panel.contentTpl?.templateRef\"></ng-template>\n          </div>\n        </div>\n      </div>\n    </ng-template>\n  "
            }]
        }];
```

NgbModule is added to main Module.

Comment: try import it using `NgbModule.forRoot()`

Comment: @ABOS I've tried and it don't work.

Comment: forRoot is for old version ng-bootstrap. sorry for the noise

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a stackblitz?

Comment: @jcubic, you must **NOT** have bootstrap, ONLY bootstrap.css. So remove "bootstrap": "^4.2.1", from your angular.json, and only add the bootstrap.css in styles tag of angular.json

Comment: @ConnorsFan is it possible to install pacakges from npm on stackblitz? I don't see an option.

Comment: @jCubic just expand the "dependencies" and add in the input

Comment: @Eliseo can you give more details? Also I don't think that boostrap have anything to do with this. JS of ng-booststrap should still work even without bootstrap.css.

Comment: @Eliseo ` "bootstrap": "^4.2.1"` is `package.json` file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have submodules you need to add `ng-bootstrap` also to that module. So in StudyModule, you have to import `ng-bootstrap` again and add it to `imports` array,

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
imports:[ ..., NgbModule ],
```

angular is very strict on this.

Comment: That was it, thanks, would never figure that out on my own. Also props for finding that I've used subModules this was my first look at the project and I've didn't nice that, I've only tried to add to Router Module.